# stack multiple columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame and would like to stack 4 columns to 2. So I have this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2023-12-01', '2023-12-05', '2023-12-07'],
'other_col':['a', 'b', 'c'],
'right_count':[4,7,9], 'right_sum':[2,3,5],
'left_count':[1,8,5], 'left_sum':[0,8,4]})
```

```
    date    other_col  right_count  right_sum   left_count  left_sum
0   2023-12-01  a          4           2           1         0
1   2023-12-05  b          7           3           8         8
2   2023-12-07  c          9           5           5         4
```

and would like to get this

```
    date    other_col   side    count   sum
0   2023-12-01  a       right   4        2
1   2023-12-05  b       right   7        3
2   2023-12-07  c       right   9        5
3   2023-12-01  a       left    1        0
4   2023-12-05  b       left    8        8
5   2023-12-07  c       left    5        4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom reshaping with a temporary MultiIndex:

```
out = (df
   .set_index(['date', 'other_col'])
   .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1))
   .rename_axis(columns=['side', None])
   .stack('side').reset_index()
)
```

Or a [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)+[`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
tmp = df.melt(['date', 'other_col'], var_name='side')
tmp[['side', 'col']] = tmp['side'].str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)

out = (tmp.pivot(index=['date', 'other_col', 'side'],
                 columns='col', values='value')
          .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
         date other_col   side  count  sum
0  2023-12-01         a   left      1    0
1  2023-12-01         a  right      4    2
2  2023-12-05         b   left      8    8
3  2023-12-05         b  right      7    3
4  2023-12-07         c   left      5    4
5  2023-12-07         c  right      9    5
```

Or, much easier, using the [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor) library and [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

out = df.pivot_longer(index=['date', 'other_col'],
                      names_to=('side', '.value'),
                      names_pattern=r'([^_]+)_([^_]+)')
```

Output:

```
         date other_col   side  count  sum
0  2023-12-01         a  right      4    2
1  2023-12-05         b  right      7    3
2  2023-12-07         c  right      9    5
3  2023-12-01         a   left      1    0
4  2023-12-05         b   left      8    8
5  2023-12-07         c   left      5    4
```

Comment: I think a names_sep works fine here too, and maybe a bit simpler in this case

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by melt function in pandas to unpivot and then manipulate  the result

```
import pandas as pd    

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2023-12-01', '2023-12-05', '2023-12-07'],
                   'other_col':['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'right_count':[4,7,9], 'right_sum':[2,3,5],
                   'left_count':[1,8,5], 'left_sum':[0,8,4]})
print(df)
# unpivot the DataFrame using melt
melted_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['date', 'other_col'], var_name='side_count_sum', value_name='value')
    
# Split the column into two separate columns
melted_df[['side', 'count_sum']] = melted_df['side_count_sum'].str.split('_', expand=True)
    
# Pivot the DataFrame 
result_df = melted_df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'other_col', 'side'], columns='count_sum', values='value').reset_index()
    
# Rename the columns
result_df.columns.name = None
result_df = result_df.rename(columns={'count': 'count', 'sum': 'sum'})

print(result_df)
```